# Known bugs in OpenGL 3, OpenGL 4 implementations

Tags: opengl, glsl, drivers, opengl-3

As we all get to know eventually, the specification is one thing and the implementation is another. Most of bugs we cause ourselves, but sometimes that's not the case.

I believe it'd be useful to make a small list of:

### What are the currently known bugs in the GPU drivers, related to the implementation of recent versions of OpenGL and GLSL?

Please remember to always post the relevant **graphics card** and **driver version**.

Comment: The question should be community wiki.

Comment: @Stringer - only mods can make questions CW now. It will still convert when >30 answers are posted.

Comment: I'm a strong supporter of an initiative listing 'known drivers bugs', but I think SO may not be the right place to be efficient. A starting point may be the OpenGL Wiki, but such a database would need searching, indexing, driver versions lists and such, it would need a proper database backend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me start:

- GPU: confirmed on AMD/ATI Radeon HD 4650
- Type: GLSL problem
- GL version related: confirmed on 3.3, probably 3.1 and up (or even before)
- Relevant link: http://forums.amd.com/devforum/messageview.cfm?catid=392&threadid=139288
- Driver version: confirmed on Catalyst 10.10 (9-28-2010)
- Status: as of 2010-11-27 it has a fix, but it aparrently didn't reach the public driver release yet (so even if the fix gets released, users with not-so-recent version of drivers will still be affected for like months)
- Description:

If in your vertex shader you have any `attribute` (`in`) variable whose name is lexically after `gl_`, then you cannot use built-in attributes, namely `gl_VertexID` and `gl_InstanceID`. If you try, the shader won't work (blank screen, likely).

- Workaround (new):

Only available with GLSL 3.3 and up, or with the [GL_ARB_explicit_attrib_location](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/explicit_attrib_location.txt) extension.

Define any attribute's location explicitly to be equal to 0, by appending `layout(location=0)` to its declaration in the vertex shader. You may, but don't need to use this for other attributes; the important thing is that ANY attribute needs to have location equal to 0. After you do that, the naming is no longer important.

- Workaround (alternative):

Use a name convention which requires you to name your attribute variables starting with `a_`, which won't hurt your code readability and will make all of them be lexically before `gl_` (safe zone).

Comment: The use of `gl_` in front of _any_ variable name except pre-defined ones is forbidden; according to the spec, you should get a compiler error.

Comment: @Nicol, that's true but not relevant to this problem. Please read again :)

Answer (score 1):

Another gl_VertexID bug:

- GPU: NVIDIA GeForce 9400M
- Type: GLSL problem
- Driver version: NVDANV50Hal 1.6.36
- OpenGL version: 2.1, GLSL 1.2 using GL_EXT_gpu_shader4 extension

This occurs on Macbooks. It's possible that the new driver enabling OpenGL 3.2 that comes with OS X Lion has fixed the issue but a lot of frameworks are only configured to use the legacy 2.1 drivers so this is still relevant.

If you read gl_VertexID before you read another attribute in a vertex shader, the latter attribute will return junk data. If the other attribute is gl_Color, regardless of how it is used, nothing will be rendered. Accessing other built-in attributes can lead to other strange behavior.

- Workaround:

If you must use gl_VertexID, read all other attributes you will need first. If you read another attribute first, followed by gl_VertexID, any subsequent reads of the attribute will work fine.